# Is there a better way to read an element from a file in Python?

Tags: python, list, csv

I have written a crude Python program to pull phrases from an index in a CSV file and write these rows to another file.

```
import csv

total = 0

ifile = open('data.csv', "rb")
reader = csv.reader(ifile)

ofile = open('newdata_write.csv', "wb")
writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

for row in reader:
    if ("some text") in row[x]:
        total = total + 1
        writer.writerow(row)
    elif ("some more text") in row[x]:
        total = total + 1   
        writer.writerow(row) 
    elif ("even more text I'm looking for") in row[x]:  
        total = total + 1   
        writer.writerow(row)

   < many, many more lines >

print "\nTotal = %d." % total

ifile.close()
```

My question is this: Isn't there a better (more elegant/less verbose) Pythonic way to do this? I feel this is a case of not knowing what I don't know. The CSV file I'm searching is not large (3863 lines, 669 KB) so I don't think it is necessary to use [SQL to solve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299454/how-do-quickly-search-through-a-csv-file-in-python), although I am certainly open to that.

I am a Python newbie, in love with the language and teaching myself through the normal channels (books, tutorials, Project Euler, Stack Overflow).

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a huge improvement, but you could do something like

```
keyphraseList = (
     "some text",
     "some more text",
     "even more text I'm looking for")

...
for row in reader:
   for phrase in keyphraseList:
       if phrase in row[x]:
           total = total + 1
           writer.writerow(row)
           break
```

(not tested)

Comment: we had the same idea, but you posted before me. However, that is that second loop necessary? `if row in keyPhraseList` should suffice.

Comment: not the whole row must be part of the keyphrase, but only a part of it suffice

Comment: @jkerian I tested this and it works as written though I omitted the parens around "(phrase)" and the `break` statement. As I'll have to update this code regularly, this seems to be the most flexible option so far. Thanks!!

Comment: @tgerhard The break just skips out of the inner loop `for phrase...` so you don't get repeats if there are multiple matches to the same row... it basically performs the same function as the `else` part of the `elif` bits of your original code.

Comment: @jkerian Ah... ok, thanks. Running it without the `break` returned more lines than my original cludge, and checking the CSV showed duplicate lines. Uncommenting the `break` solved that problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for [`any`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) with a generator expression:

```
matches = "some text", "some more text", "even more text I'm looking for"
for row in reader:
    if any(match in row for match in matches):  
        total += 1   
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Alternatively, you could just write all the rows at once:

```
writer.writerows(row for row in reader if any(match in row for match in matches))
```

but as written that doesn't get you a total.

Comment: Thanks for this - the first option works just fine once I added the row element `row[n]`. I haven't tried the second option yet since it is handy for my purposes to have a total. Thanks again!

Comment: @tgerhard If an answer solved your problem, you can click the check mark next to it to accept it. You can also vote up any helpful answers if you want by clicking the up arrow above the score.

Answer (score 0):

not necessairly, 'better', but I would compare the item to a set and clean up total a bit. It may not be 'better' but it is more succinct

### This

```
for row in reader:
    if ("some text") in row[x]:
        total = total + 1
        writer.writerow(row)
    elif ("some more text") in row[x]:
        total = total + 1   
        writer.writerow(row) 
    elif ("even more text I'm looking for") in row[x]:  
        total = total + 1   
        writer.writerow(row)
```

### becomes

```
myWords = set(('some text','some more text','even more'))
for row in reader:
     if row[x] in myWords: 
          total += 1
          writer.writerow(row)
```

you could just use a simple list, but sets become quicker on more memory intensive tasks.

in response to the comment by agf

```
>>> x = set(('something','something else'))
>>> Ture if 'some' in x else False
False
>>> True if 'something' in x else False
True
```

is this what your saying would not work?

Comment: This isn't the same. If `row[x]` is `blah` and one of the matches is `bl`, this won't match, whereas the original will.

Comment: incorrect? you mean like this. 
EDIT: see my response appended to my answer

Comment: okay, I am worried. I dont understand how mine is different. if row[x] = 'some text' and 'some text' is in x than this would be True? what is the problem? I'll take a look at this after lunch, perhaps I'll understand better.

Comment: if `row[x]` is _exactly_ the text in the match, it is equivalent. But if there is _more text_ in `row[x]`, then reversing the `in` won't match, as it doesn't perform `in` tests on each item in the list, it performs `==` tests -- the `in` is applied to the list, not the strings inside it.

Comment: Right, that is simple enough, but I was under the impression that this was what he was after. 'some text' should not equal 'some text in a longer string', when he said an indexed list I thought he was looking for a particular key.

Comment: My point was that it isn't what his current code does. As he asked for a more elegant method to do the same thing, we have to assume that his code works as currently written. Your version would work differently.

Comment: fair enough. Point understood. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

You can get pythonic by using list comprehensions instead of for loops.  For example, if you are looking for index strings 'aa' or 'bb', you could do

```
matches = [row for row in reader if 'aa' in row[0] or 'bb' in row[0]]
```

Comment: this does not increase 'total' nor writes to 'writer'

Comment: But the questions asked for a "more elegant, less verbose" way to write it, not a higher performance solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this version is better, just shorter, anyway hope it helps

```
import csv

total = 0

keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
with open('infile', 'rb') as infile, open('outfile', 'wb') as outfile:
    rows = [x for x in csv.reader(infile) if any([k in x[0] for k in keys])]
    csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL).writerows(rows)

print 'Total: %d' % len(rows)
```