# How to get the same name with multiple value get unique results in Python

Tags: python

I have a large csv file that compares the URLs of my txt files

How to get the same name with multiple value get unique results in Python and Is there a way to better compare the speed of two files? because it has a minimum large csv file of 1 gb

file1.csv

```
[01/Nov/2019:09:54:26 +0900] ","","102.12.14.22","34.122.104.106","200","CONNECT","http://www.amazon.com/asdd/asd/","555976","1508"
[01/Nov/2019:09:54:26 +0900] ","","164.16.37.75","52.222.194.116","200","CONNECT","http://www.google.com:443","555976","1508"
[01/Nov/2019:09:54:26 +0900] ","","167.27.14.62","34.122.104.106","200","CONNECT","http://www.amazon.com/asdd/asd/","555976","1508"
[01/Nov/2019:09:54:26 +0900] ","","192.10.77.95","21.323.12.96","200","CONNECT","http://www.wakers.com/sg/wew/","555976","1508"
[01/Nov/2019:09:54:26 +0900] ","","167.27.14.62","34.122.104.106","200","CONNECT","http://www.amazon.com/asdd/asd/","555976","1508"
[01/Nov/2019:09:54:26 +0900] ","","197.99.94.32","34.122.104.106","200","CONNECT","http://www.amazon.com/asdd/asd/","555976","1508"
[01/Nov/2019:09:54:26 +0900] ","","157.87.34.72","34.122.104.106","200","CONNECT","http://www.amazon.com/asdd/asd/","555976","1508"
```

file2.txt

```
1 www.amazon.com shop
1 wakers.com shop
```

script:

```
import csv
with open("file1.csv", 'r') as f: 
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for k in reader:
        ko = set()
        srcip = k[2]
        url = k[6]
        lines = url.replace(":443", "").replace(":8080", "")
        war = lines.split("//")[-1].split("/")[0].split('?')[0]
        ko.add((war,srcip))
        for to in ko:
            with open("file2.txt", "r") as f:
                all_val = set()
                for i in f:
                    val = i.strip().split(" ")[1]
                    if val in to[0]:
                        all_val.add(to)
                for ki in all_val:
                  print(ki)
```

my output:

```
('www.amazon.com', '102.12.14.22')
('www.amazon.com', '167.27.14.62')
('www.wakers.com', '192.10.77.95')
('www.amazon.com', '167.27.14.62')
('www.amazon.com', '197.99.94.32')
('www.amazon.com', '157.87.34.72')
```

how to get if the url is the same, get the total value with a unique value

how to get results like this?

```
amazon.com    102.12.14.22 
              167.27.14.62 
              197.99.94.32
              157.87.34.72
wakers.com    192.10.77.95
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't directly do so. Well you can but with low performances.

CSV is a good storing format but if you want to do something like that you might want to store everything in another custom data file. you could first parse your file to have only Unique IDs instead of long strings (like amazon = 0, wakers = 1 and so on) to perform better and reduce compare cost.

The thing is, those thing are pretty bad for variable csv, memory mapping or building a database from your csv might also be great though (and making the changes on the database,  only dumping the csv when you need to)

look at: [How do quickly search through a .csv file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299454/how-do-quickly-search-through-a-csv-file-in-python) for a more complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem solution

```py
import csv
import re


def possible_urls(filename, category, category_position, url_position):
  # Here we will read a txt file to create a list of domains, that could correspond to shops
  domains = []
  with open(filename, "r") as file:
      file_content = file.read().splitlines()
  for line in file_content:
      info_in_line = line.split(" ")
      # Here i use a regular expression, to prase domain from url.
      domain = re.sub('www.', '', info_in_line[url_position])
      if info_in_line[category_position] == category:
          domains.append(domain)
  return domains


def read_from_csv(filename, ip_position, url_position, possible_domains):
  # Here we will create a dictionary, where will 
  # all ips that this domain can have.
  # Dictionary will look like this:
  # {domain_name: [list of possible ips]}

  domain_ip = {domain: [] for domain in possible_domains}
  with open(filename, 'r') as f:
      reader = csv.reader(f)
      for line in reader:
          if len(line) < max(ip_position, url_position):
              print(f'Not enough items in line {line}, to obtain url or ip')
              continue
          ip = line[ip_position]
          url = line[url_position]
          # Using python regular expression to get a domain name
          # from url.
          domain = re.search('//[w]?[w]?[w]?\.?(.[^/]*)[:|/]', url).group(1)
          if domain in domain_ip.keys():
              domain_ip[domain].append(ip)
  return domain_ip


def print_fomatted_result(result):
  # Prints formatted result
  for shop_domain in result.keys():
      print(f'{shop_domain}: ')
      for shop_ip in result[shop_domain]:
          print(f'              {shop_ip}')


def create_list_of_shops():
  # Function that first creates a list of possible domains, and
  # then read ip for that domains from csv
  possible_domains = possible_urls('file2.txt', 'shop', 2, 1)
  shop_domains_with_ip = read_from_csv('file1.csv', 2, 6, possible_domains)
  # Display result, we get in previous operations
  print(shop_domains_with_ip)
  print_fomatted_result(shop_domains_with_ip)


create_list_of_shops()
```

### Output

Dictionary of ip's where domains are keys, so you can get all possible ip's for domain by giving a name of that domain:

```py
{'amazon.com': ['102.12.14.22', '167.27.14.62', '167.27.14.62', '197.99.94.32', '157.87.34.72'], 'wakers.com': ['192.10.77.95']}
```

```py
amazon.com: 
              102.12.14.22
              167.27.14.62
              167.27.14.62
              197.99.94.32
              157.87.34.72
wakers.com: 
              192.10.77.95
```

### Regular expressions

A very useful thing you can learn from the solution is regular expressions. Regular expressions are tools that allow you to filter or retrieve information from lines in a very convenient way. It also greatly reduces the amount of code, which makes the code more readable and safe. 
Let's consider your code of removing ports from strings and  think how we can replace it with regex.

```py
        lines = url.replace(":443", "").replace(":8080", "")
```

Replacing of ports in such way is vulnerable, because you never can be sure, what port numbers can actually be in url. What if there will appear port number 5460, or port number 1022, etc.  For each of such ports you will add new replaces and soon your code will look something like this

```py
lines = url.replace(":443", "").replace(":8080", "").replace(":5460","").replace(":1022","")...
```

Not very readable. But with regular experssion you can describe a pattern. And the great news is that we actually know pattern for url with port numbers. They all looking like this:
`:some_digits`. So if we know pattern we can describe it with regular expression, and tell python to find everything, that match it and replace with empty string `''`:

`re.sub(':\d+', '', url)`

It tells to python regular expression engine:
Look for all digits in string `url`, that goes after `:` and replace them with empty string. This solution is shorter, safer and a way more readable then solution with replace chain, so I suggest you to read about them a little. Great resource to learn about regular expressions is
[this site](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). Here you can [test](https://regex101.com/) your regex.

### Explanation of Regular expressions in code

```py
re.sub('www.', '', info_in_line[url_position])
```

Look for all `www.` in string  `info_in_line[url_position]` and replace it with empty string.

```py
re.search('www.(.[^/]*)[:|/]', url).group(1)
```

Let's split it on parts:

1. `[^/]` - here could be everything except `/`
2. `(.[^/]*)` - Here i used [match group](https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups). It tells to engine where solution we intersted in will be.
3. `[:|/]` - it means characters that could stay on that place. Long story short: after capturing group could be `:` or(`|`) `/`. 
   So summarizing. Regex can be expressed in words as follows:
   Find all substrings, that starts with `www.`, and ends with `:` or `\` and return me everything that stadns between them.
   `group(1)` - means get the first match.

Hope answer will be helpful!

Comment: that shows some error
 `domain = re.search('www.(.[^/]*)[:|/]', url).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: Can you please insert 
`print(url)`
before `domain = re.search('www.(.[^/]*)[:|/]', url).group(1)`
and send here last printed url

Comment: "print(url)" shows all urls
`http://www.amazon.com/asdd/asd/
{}`

Comment: None type error means, that regex doesn't find any patterns. The possible reason is that you have urls, that doesn't start with `www.` in your file. I will try to change the regular expression to match that types of patterns and edit posted code.

Comment: `domain = re.search('//[w]?[w]?[w]?\.?(.[^/]*)[:|/]', url).group(1)` Here is the fixed regular expression. Now it matches also urls, that have no www. before it. Like `https://regex101.com/` 
Try to replace that line and write back please

Comment: same error message and for regex does not read "http", so it shows error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206286/discussion-between-bohdan-forostianyi-and-angeline).

Answer (score 0):

If you used the URL as the key in a dictionary, and had your IP address sets as the elements of the dictionary, would that achieve what you intended?

```py
my_dict = {
    'www.amazon.com' = {
        '102.12.14.22',
        '167.27.14.62',
        '197.99.94.32',
        '157.87.34.72',
    },
    'www.wakers.com' = {'192.10.77.95'},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
## I have used your code & Pandas to get your desired output
## Copy paste the code & execute to get the result

import csv

url_dict = {}

## STEP 1: Open file2.txt to get url names
with open("file2.txt", "r") as f:      
    for i in f:                      
        val = i.strip().split(" ")[1]       
        url_dict[val] = []      

## STEP 2: 2.1 Open csv file 'file1.csv' to extract url name & ip address
##         2.2 Check if url from file2.txt is available from the extracted url from 'file1.csv'
##         2.3 Create a dictionary with the matched url & its ip address 
##         2.4 Remove duplicates in ip addresses from same url          
with open("file1.csv", 'r') as f: ## 2.1
    reader = csv.reader(f)    

    for k in reader:
        #ko = set()        
        srcip = k[2]
        #print(srcip)
        url = k[6]
        lines = url.replace(":443", "").replace(":8080", "")
        war = lines.split("//")[-1].split("/")[0].split('?')[0]  

        for key, value in url_dict.items(): 
            if key in war:                   ## 2.2
            url_dict[key].append(srcip)   ## 2.3          

## 2.4
for key, value in url_dict.items():    
    url_dict[key] = list(set(value))

## STEP 3: Print dictionary output to .TXT file 
file3 = open('output_text.txt', 'w')    
for key, value in url_dict.items():                  
    file3.write('\n' + key + '\n')            
    for item in value:   
        file3.write(' '*15 + item + '\n')

file3.close()
```

Comment: How do I write this print value in a csv or txt file for url with ip one by one?

Comment: I have edited the above code. I have added STEP 5 to redirect print output to .csv file and STEP 6 to redirect print output to .txt file. This program is redirecting output to both .csv file & .txt file. Remove code between STEP 5: START & END or STEP 6: START & END to retain the code which writes either to .csv or .txt format.

Comment: Why does the file create the csv twice again?
CSV to create the same GB for IP and URL if the file has a minimum of 2GB Because many gb files are read

Comment: You are right about it. I have updated the code to avoid using an extra csv file.

Comment: step 3 is also not necessary

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have edited code to remove step 3 & rename step 4 as step 3.